# Can't start mysql server in xampp,

Tags: mysql, xampp

1. I have tried deleting ib files.
2. I have tried to change mysql port.
3. tried to run xampp as Run as.
   Administrator.
4. tried to reinstall xampp.
5. tried to delete data folder from.
   mysql, and it worked but i have
   data in that folder.

Comment: Did you stop to look at the error logs to find out what the problem was before doing all this?

Comment: Removed unnecessary TAGS

Comment: What exactly does "i have data in that folder" (mysql) mean? If there's data in that folder before MySQL initializes the DB files, it will complain. If it was completely empty there shouldn't be a problem starting off with a clean installation. Check for mysql startup errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly just for my understanding why didnt you flag this question to be closed as it is not development related? -. Sorry Recker Rodgers for spamming your question with administrative questions

Comment: @Harry Because I think XAMPP and WAMPServer etc etc questions are definitely development related. Cannot start dev'ing till I get an environment up :) I know this leaves me out on a limb a bit, but .....

Comment: Recker, you seem to have thrown multiple valid solutions at a probelm that you have yet to identify !! Are you using Windows or Linux

Comment: @Recker Rodgers remove xampp completely and install it again. Also don't delete any data on your own like you did for mysql that can cause mis-configuration.

Comment: @RiggsFoly im using windows.

Comment: @Ankit jindal i tried that and i also mentioned that in my post, and i haven't deleted any data.